# Network connectivity

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have a switch in my room with 2 machines connected. There is another switch in another room connected to a DHCP server. One of the two machines in my room can access the network past the switch in my room and it gets its IP dynamically from the DHCP server from the other room.. However, the other machine in my room can't reach outside the network on the switch in my room.

The two machines in my room can ping each other fine.

The network is: 192.168.2.0 and the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0

Comment: Do both machines in the "problem" room get a default gateway? Does the problem machine get an IP on the 192.168.2.X network?  Does the DHCP server have available IPs?

Comment: Yes, both machines have a default gateway (192.168.2.1), the problem machine has a statically assigned network address that isn't inside of the DHCP range. I'm trying to statically assign an IP to the problem machine (and it works) but I can't connect to anything(outside of the network in my room) from the problem machine.

Comment: Does it work if you set it to DHCP?

Comment: Can you post ip/mask/gw/routes info for all 3 machines and DHCP config of server?

Comment: If it can't connect to anything outside my switch's network, then no, it cannot get an address from my DHCP server outside of my switches network. And the configurations are correct because I took the network cable from my working machine and connected it directly to my non-working computer and then took the cable from the non-working computer and put it in my originally working computer (after the problem computer was connected and fully working) and it wouldn't identify the network. All of the physical ethernet cables are terminated correctly and work fine.